# Rails 4.2.0 + passenger + apache + Custom Engines - how to reload properly?

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm deploying rails 4.2.0 app with passenger5 and apache2 on Ubuntu12.04 server.

When I pull the new version of the app from github I need to reload the app for changes to come into effect.

My custom Engines are 'required' in the Gemfile as proposed in the Rails Guide

```
gem 'CustomeEngine', path: "lib/engines/CustomeEngine"
```

Based on passenger Documentation we can reload the web server by creating this file:

```
touch ${MYAPP}/tmp/restart.txt
```

When I make changes in CustomeEngine's code Rails seems not to reload the CustomeEngine with the restart.txt methode.

Please help me understand how to reload rails properly.

Best answer for me would be how do I do this in 'one line' of bash. Pull changes from github and reload the App which is running inside of a passenger process.

Thank you in advance!